# Выборка из двух таблиц

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть две таблицы:

[image]

В результате выборке необходимо получить вот такую таблицу:

[image]

То есть необходимо узнать сколько отличников имеет каждая школа. Как должен выглядеть  SQL-запрос (T-SQL)?

Comment: @derkode, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Это не учебное задание. Я делаю анализ результатов ЕГЭ в своем регионе. Привел такой пример для наглядности.

Comment: @derkode, вам нужно сделать выборку из только таблицы `TableB` с группировкой по полю `ID школы`, агрегацией `COUNT` по полю `Оценка` и условием `Оценка=5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select a.id, count(b.school_id)
from tablea as a
left join tableb as b on a.id = b.school_id
where b.point = 5
group by a.id
```

Comment: left join + where = inner join

Comment: 1. Предположим, что в таблице TableB появилась запись "1001 Вася 3". Как inner join поможет вместо where?
2. Предположим, что в таблице TableA появилась запись "1003 Школа№3". Как inner join покажет в этой школе 0 отличников?

Comment: @kirill mazurik, вы напрасно задаете вопросы, ответы на которые могли бы сами получить.

будет один и тот же результат.

1. `b.point=5` что в `where`, что в `inner join'е` отфильтрует только отличников и Вася в выборку не попадет.
2. для такой записи `b.point = NULL`, запись не будет выбрана. и записи с нулевым количеством вы не получите.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe111/1

ЗЫ Чтоб получить 0 отличников в 1003 школе, вам надо убрать либо выражение `where` и считать количество в выражении `select` через `case`, либо в выражении `where` учиывать `null` в виде `b.point=5 or b.point is null`.

Comment: 1. Подробно и с самого начала:
Посыл "left join + where = inner join" говорит о том, что я могу заменить left join + where на inner join и получу такой же результат. Я правильно понял?
Я делаю замену и добавляю в таблицу TableB запись вида "1001 Вася 3" и получаю вариант когда помимо отличника учелся еще и Вася-троечник. Так?
Я не понимаю как inner join отфильтрует отличников? Такое возможно только с отличниками? А если у меня 100-бальная система оценок (или вообще не про оценки идет речь), то что будет фильтровать inner join?

2. Признаю. Этот вопрос лишний.

Comment: @kirill mazurik, вы посмотрите [филд](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe111/3) - этот чуть подробнее. эти запросы эквивалентны. а посыл был таков, что там, где вы применяете left join он не даст никаких других записей в совокупности в вашим where, а только те, которые вернет inner join.  
Когда пишут такие запросы с left join'ом, ставя where, то либо ожидают какого-то побочного эффекта (как у вас во втором снятом вами пункте), либо "все ставят left join, ну и я буду".  
Это неаккуратно. И если есть подозрения, что эти запросы отличаются, срочно избавьтесь от них.